# Is there any way to read Linux Desktop Notification with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, notifications, dbus, notify

I need to read Linux Desktop Notification with Python. My head ran out of ideas and I can't think of an method of doing that.

This is the best I can do using dbus:

```py
import gi.repository.GLib
import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

def notifications(bus, message):
    print(str(message))
DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

bus = dbus.SessionBus()
bus.add_match_string_non_blocking("eavesdrop=true, interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications', member='Notify'")
bus.add_message_filter(notifications)

mainloop = gi.repository.GLib.MainLoop()
mainloop.run()
```

Seems that this code just returns objects from GLib

Answer (score 1):

The `message` you have in `notification` are different `dbus.**.*Message` instances, so this is what gets printed.

Try `for arg in message.get_args_list(): print(arg)`, and you might find what you seek.